# Why doesn't the JSON-Simple parser expect a colon, in Java?

Tags: json, bufferedreader, json-simple

I'm parsing a JSON block from twitter using JSON-Simple. I've run into an excepton:

`Exception in thread "main" Unexpected token COLON(:) at position 27`
`...stack 
trace...`

I've seen something similar on SO due to some specialness in the way JavaScript parses JSON (I think that JSONJ-P needs to recieve it padded) but this isn't the case here as I'm not in JS!

Here is my JSON (sanitized):

`{"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"id_str":"23475129874512857","text":"RT @SanitizedPersonName: SomeTextIveSanitized @SanatizedTwitterHandle SomeMoreText http:\/\/t.co\/sanitized SomeText (MoreText) \/ Text", "restOfTheJson":"Is not Special"}`

Two things strike me.

1. It prints out the line that it just read with buffered reader, and that doesn't have a `{` at the start of the block it does at the end. This seems like a serious issue.
2. The character I read at position 27 is not a colon but `r`

So either buffered reader is eating my `{` or the parser is not parsing correctly. How do I tell which is it and fix the issue?

n.b. I do have my print and parse line inside a `while(buff.read()!=-1)` (to check for line end) and an if statement that checks for a 'regex' `(if(!line.contains(DELETE_REGEX))` (to check for invalid jsons) could this be the cause? Here is the code:

```
buff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(JSON_FILE_NAME+".json"));
while(buff.read() != -1){
    line = buff.readLine();
    if(!line.contains(DELETE_REGEX)){
        System.out.println(line);
        myJSON=(JSONObject) parser.parse(line);
        myJSONSample.add(myJSON);
    }
}
return myJSONSample;
```

I've missed out some inconsequential stuff.

Comment: Does the sanitised version actually reproduce the problem? I get a different error, and when I fix it I get no complaints about any colon.

Comment: You have a missing opening quote mark in your first key (`in_reply_to_status_id_str`).

Comment: @Quentin are you using a buffered reader like I am (or as close as you can from what I've given)? I've fixed the error that lanzz

Comment: @lanzz thanks that was a transcription error.

Comment: Perhaps you should post the code for your loop where you're decoding the JSON.

Comment: I'm not decoding it though, I'll write out the loop again anyway.

Comment: So you receive one JSON per line? Are you sure you don't have an embedded newline somewhere in your JSON, splitting it into two lines, each containing an incomplete JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found it. `buff.read()` was eating the first `char` of each line making it impossible to parse it as a json. I'd revert to `while((line=buff.readLine())!=null)` to check for EOR, but that doesn't work.